# Dell Inspiron 1545 wireless driver not working in Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit

Tags: wireless, drivers, dell, broadcom

I have used Mythbuntu, Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit OS, and they have all worked properly with the wifi driver which is apparently the Broadcom 4312. Then I deleted the Linux partitions, rebooted with Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit because that was the only 64-bit version I could find. I did it through USB boot, installed alongside my Windows 7.

I noticed before installing that it couldn't detect wifi connections so I used ethernet. It installed as quickly as the 32-bit version of 12.10. I finally got to the desktop environment after rebooting, and I noticed that I still couldn't connect to my wireless internet. I've browsed for hours and hours to get it working, but I still have found no answer. I hope someone can help give me a working yet simple solution. If not then I guess lay it down on me the hard way.

Comment: Have you tried this ? http://askubuntu.com/q/55868/35775

Comment: yeah but i havent been able to use any of those,they all seemed valuable but broken links and/or not the right thing,im scared because its been a problem for several years and still unfixed

Comment: What is the exact identity of your Broadcom? Run this terminal command and pick out the Broadcom wireless. Edit your question to add all the details: lspci -nn

Comment: it says Broacom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY

Comment: I think it says more than that. The 'more' is what I need to see: 14e4:????

Comment: (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 0

Comment: thats about everything from the second half of the terminal

Comment: I still don't see the numbers. Did you add the -nn flag to the terminal command? lspci -nn  I just hate to guess and give you a frustrating and wrong solution.

Comment: no and ill do that now

Comment: 0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)

Comment: E: Unable to locate package bcmwl E: Package 'kernel-source' has no installation candidate warren@warren-Inspiron-1545:~$ sudo modprobe wl FATAL: Module wl not found. warren@warren-Inspiron-1545:~$ –

Answer (score 5):

Your device, 14e4:4315 uses the Broadcom STA driver. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Assuming the wireless switch is on, your wireless should now be working; check:

```
rfkill list all
```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package bcmwl
E: Package 'kernel-source' has no installation candidate
warren@warren-Inspiron-1545:~$ sudo modprobe wl
FATAL: Module wl not found.
warren@warren-Inspiron-1545:~$

Comment: Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
ERROR: Module b43 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module b43legacy does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module ssb does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcm43xx does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcm80211 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmfmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmsmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcma does not exist in /proc/modules
FATAL: Module wl not found.
update-initramfs

Comment: 'kernel source missing' indicates that linux-headers was not installed or installed incorrectly. Please try again: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic and then do sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) and then try again: sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source ; sudo modprobe wl

Comment: It looks like you typed bcmwl kernel-source; it is actually bcmwl-kernel-source.

Comment: Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
ERROR: Module b43 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module b43legacy does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module ssb does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcm43xx does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcm80211 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmfmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmsmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcma does not exist in /proc/modules
FATAL: Module wl not found.
very aggravating

Comment: im gonna try again

Comment: can this be resolved via remote desktop?

Comment: just copy paste the commands.

Comment: alright well the last error message is what i get from the commands :(

Comment: Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed. ERROR: Module b43 does not exist in /proc/modules ERROR: Module b43legacy does not exist in /proc/modules ERROR: Module ssb does not exist in /proc/modules ERROR: Module bcm43xx does not exist in /proc/modules ERROR: Module brcm80211 does not exist in /proc/modules ERROR: Module brcmfmac does not exist in /proc/modules ERROR: Module brcmsmac does not exist in /proc/modules ERROR: Module bcma does not exist in /proc/modules FATAL: Module wl not found

Comment: Run each command one at a time and post the result: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic. How does this go?

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  calligra-l10n-engb cdparanoia k3b k3b-data k3b-i18n kde-l10n-engb
  kde-l10n-zhcn kdevelop-l10n kdevelop-php-docs-l10n
  kdevelop-php-l10n language-pack-kde-en libflac++6 libk3b6
  libkcddb4 module-assistant
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 74 not upgraded.
warren@warren-Inspiron-1545:~$

Comment: We really ought to update before we continue: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade. Please post any errors or warnings. The whole output is unnecessary unless there is something alarming.

Comment: so far this,dont know how important this is

Comment: 73 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded

Comment: Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'

Comment: Please restart all running instances of firefox, or you will experience problems.

Comment: I think we're OK so far. Now the next one: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) Result, please? It may, I hope, say it's already installed.

Comment: The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.5.0-25 linux-headers-3.5.0-25-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 70.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?

Comment: Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.5.0-25-generic.
Unpacking linux-headers-3.5.0-25-generic (from .../linux-headers-3.5.0-25-generic_3.5.0-25.39_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.5.0-25 (3.5.0-25.39) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.5.0-25-generic (3.5.0-25.39) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.5.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic

Comment: I assume you said Y. If not, please do so and then please go on to the next one: sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source  We're close, Warren!

Comment: wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

Comment: ERROR: Module b43 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module b43legacy does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module ssb does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcm43xx does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcm80211 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmfmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmsmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcma does not exist in /proc/modules
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic

Comment: Ok, now how about: sudo modprobe wl??

Comment: warren@warren-Inspiron-1545:~$ sudo modprobe wl
warren@warren-Inspiron-1545:~$

Comment: So now is your wireless working after you detach the ethernet?

Comment: ahhhh :"D ITS ALIVE!!!!! thanks,you're the best,do i require rebooting? ,oh and before i got rid of 32 bit version,i got rid of it because it was only a read only file system,would i worry about this in 64 bit?

Comment: I would do nothing but enjoy your wireless. Update Manager will probably want to install whatever was skipped above. Please accept my answer above and have fun! I doubt you will have any read-only issues but post a question here if so.

Comment: Problem solved for me in DELL inspiron 1545 (broadcom) + Ubuntu 12.10 (may need to prss fn+F2 to enable wireless )

Comment: You've got a lot of patience! ;-)  (upvote!)