# Wireless not working when using UBUNTU 13.04 on DELL Precision M6300

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.04, dell

I installed UBUNTU 13.04  dual boot with Windows 8. 
all working perfectly well except my wireless.
the wireless does not turn on or off. neither it detects any wireless system.
Fn+F2 does not turn on or off the wireless network. the light indication of Wi-Fi also doesnt turn on. it is off constantly.
i think it contains:  Dell Wireless 1390 or 1395 WLAN MiniCard.
plx help asap! waiting.

Comment: Try following the steps here: http://askubuntu.com/a/266278/52726 and let us know what happens.

Comment: Have you already connected to a hard line (ethernet cable) so Linux can auto update the WiFi drivers?

Answer (score 0):

1st you have to see if it's used by the system 
go to *settings >> software & updates >> additional driver* 
 
and check to use the wireless adapter by system if it's not used 
if it's not working reply me i'll help

Answer (score 0):

go to Software Sources in System settings (think its called software and updates now) the last tab is addition drivers , select that and active the Broadcom driver