# Wireless is not wokring after a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04 on Vostro 3400

Tags: wireless, 13.04, 64-bit, dell-vostro

I have done a fresh installation of Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit recently on my Dell Vostro 3400.But sadly my wi-fi is not working at all now. It can detects the network but it doesn't connect to it at all. Before that it used to work fine in Ubuntu 12.10.

**I have tried almost all the answers given by people on the forum for this problem but could not resolve my problem.**

Here is output I get from the command `lspci - nn`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0044] (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller [8086:3b64] (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b3c] (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [8086:3b56] (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:3b42] (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:3b44] (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:3b46] (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:3b4a] (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b34] (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller [8086:3b0b] (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:3b2f] (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller [8086:3b30] (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem [8086:3b32] (rev 06)
**12:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)**
13:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
ff:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder [8086:2d01] (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 [8086:2d10] (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 [8086:2d11] (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved [8086:2d12] (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved [8086:2d13] (rev 05)
```

Please suggest me some solutions for it. In addition to this problem my system freezes a lot, I don't know the exact problem for it. In older version of Ubuntu I have never faced this problem.

Comment: Try following the steps here: http://askubuntu.com/a/266278/52726.

Comment: I have tried this previously as well but it did not work for me.

Comment: Okay, take a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/a/60395/52726. Scroll down to the _Special Cases (BCM4313, BCM4321, BCM4312, BCM43142, BCM4365, BCM43228)_ section. Have you done those 1 to 3 steps? I think they should do the trick. If not, follow the rest of the instructions.

Comment: It seems there is already a bug filed by some people with BCM4313 on Ubuntu 13.04. Anyways thanks for the suggestions and this much help.

Answer (score 0):

There ia more than one broadcom 4313 device, which I suspect has been part of the problem.

This is what worked for me from the forums.  My adapter is [14e4:4727] (rev 01), same as the OP.

First I got the latest broadcom firmware updates:

```
wget media.cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/56/18/5007272-Broadcom_Firmware_070513.tar.gz
sudo tar xvf 5007272-Broadcom_Firmware_070513.tar.gz -C /lib/firmware
```

Then I installed the broadcom sta driver by installing the bcmwl-kernel-source package in synaptic.  I've come to trust syna[tic more than additional drivers.

Hope it'd work as well for you.  Original thread:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2148444&page=2